# Should I remove the part about my efforts once my question is answered?

Tags: discussion, support

When I ask a question I think it is curcial to show my efforts as well what I will further try (beside waiting for answers on Stack Overflow).

Escpecially if my efforts contain certain assumptations that may be wrong at all or compared to the question are way longer - having found a accepted answer and some interst in the question I somethimes think it would make sence to remove my efforts to provide a "clean, small, essential" question without any assumptations (that in the case bellow were wrong) that could lead to a missunderstanding of the topic (or on the other hand lead to a better understanding by showing *"no especially such assumptations are not relevant in this context"*) .

Have a look at this question [What is the difference when concatenating a String as a variable with a Character vs concatenating with an other String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855610/what-is-the-difference-when-concatenating-a-string-as-a-variable-with-a-characte) would it in terms of Stack Overflow make sence to remove the parts **what I tried**/ **what I will try** or is it considered bad practise (because the question would look like I never had to show my own efforts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about your efforts as well as for the other users, who come across your post while searching out for a solution for their programming problems .Moreover it will be useful for someone  in one way or another. The reader might read your problem and say, "Oh yea, I have not tried this so far, but if I had, I would be asking the same question as the OP did".

Remember it is always

- good to learn
- and to learn from someone else's experiences.

Because we don't have to jump from the 60th floor of a building to know the fact that we will be dead, *it is good to know upfront* that the one who  tried that jump  is dead, so I should not do that. :)

Comment: This sounds legit to me - i will in this case leave my questions as they are :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with that last sentence.

Comment: @BillWoodger **Learn from other's experiences** simple

Comment: Mmmm... You could just have said that rather than try something more complicated. Learn from your experience. Even after two edits, if we don't have to jump to know, then what use is knowing that someone actually died doing it? Let alone that you term it "good". Plus, have you heard of wrapping yourself in Bubblewrap? Parachutes? The latter get used all the time for far taller near-ground jumps. Keep it simple.